# How to create login form in Express JS or Node JS?

Tags: node.js, express

Express JS is a popular framework of Node JS to create web apps and Restful API. As it is used for backend scripting, form processing is its important part. I would like to know how we can create login form and process it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [Pug templating engine](https://learncybers.com/frontend-templating-pug-engine-in-express-js/) to make HTML simplified.

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title Login Form
    body
        form(method="POST", action="/submit")
            label(for = "username") Username:
            input(type = "text", name = "username")
            br
            label(for = "password") Password:
            input(type = "password", name = "password")
            br
            input(type = "submit", name = "submit", value = "submit")
```

Following is Express JS or Node JS code for processing above form.

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let multer = require('multer');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views','./views');
app.use('/static', express.static('public'));
app.use(multer().array());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(request, response){
    console.log(request.body);
    response.render('login');
});
app.post('/submit', function(request, response){
    console.log(request.body);
    response.send("Data for " + request.body.username + " submitted successfully!");
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Reference: [How to create and process login form in Express JS or Node JS](https://learncybers.com/create-process-form-with-login-example-in-express-js/)

Comment: Is this part of your question or that's your answer?

Comment: @goto1 This is complete answer to my question.